# cmake under msys2 fails due to compiler extension (gcc.exe)

Tags: gcc, cmake, clang, msys2

I am using MSYS2 under Windows 10 to compile a few dependencies (boost etc) with the clang64 environment (mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-toolchain).

A minimum reproducible example would be like this:

```bash
###### PATHS #######
CC=$(which gcc)
CXX=$(which g++)
BUILD_DIR=/tmp

###### create dirs
cd ${BUILD_DIR}
rm -rf test
mkdir -p test
cd test

##### Cmake project
cat << EOF > CMakeLists.txt
project(test)
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.0 )
add_executable(test test.cpp)
install( TARGETS test DESTINATION bin )
EOF

##### Test files
cat << EOF > test.cpp
int main() {}
EOF
cat << EOF > test.c
int main() {}
EOF

##### Build
mkdir -p build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=$CC -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=$CXX -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${PWD}
cmake --build . --target install
```

This simple project fails with the following messages:

```
$ bash x.sh
-- Building for: Ninja
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 14.0.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 14.0.4
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    G:/msys64/clang64/bin/gcc

  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

The compiler detected with `which(gcc)` is `/clang64/bin/gcc` that cmake automagically translates into `G:/msys64/clang64/bin/gcc`. This path is imaginary as the actual binary lives at `G:/msys64/clang64/bin/gcc.exe`.

From Unix the path in fact "exists" but this is only a view of `gcc.exe`

```
$ ls -l G:/msys64/clang64/bin/gcc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Fred None 146944 Jun 17 11:22 G:/msys64/clang64/bin/gcc
```

If I provide the correct windows path, cmake does not like it a bit.
So my solution is then to make a double conversion to Windows and then from Windows into Unix.

```bash
CC=$(which gcc)
CXX=$(which g++)
source /etc/os-release
if [ "$ID" == "msys2" ];  then
    CC=$(cygpath -w $CC)
    CXX=$(cygpath -w $CXX)
    CC=$(cygpath -u "$CC")
    CXX=$(cygpath -u "$CXX")
fi
```

This works but it seems too wrong. Am I missing anything? Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: Why do you specify `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=$CC -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=$CXX` in the cmake call, aren't they found automatically anyways?

Comment: @ssbssa I do not want them to be found automatically.  I have to build on very old OSs like RH6/7 and I compile my own clang 14.0 on those boxes. I want to use that, not the OS own compiler.

Comment: Which MSYS2 environment are you running (what does the magenta text in the terminal prompt say, is it `CLANG64`)? How did you install CMake?